# SQL Server OFFSET equivalent

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise on Windows Server 2008. I want to select result from top 11 to top 20 (e.g. I am only interested in the 11th to the 20th result). Any ideas how to write this query in tsql efficiently?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: SQL Server OFFSET equivalent present 2012 onwards. See [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9261797/1045444).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately SQL Server does not offer anything similar to MySQL's `OFFSET` syntax. However, you may want to try using a derived table as follows:

```
SELECT some_field
FROM   (
          SELECT some_field, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_id) AS rownum
          FROM   table
       ) AS t
WHERE  t.rownum BETWEEN 11 AND 20
```

Comment: Must I have order by some_id?

Comment: @George2: Since tables in relational databases are just sets of unordered records, you have to order the result set by one (or more) unique column(s) in order for pagination to make sense. Otherwise, how can you say that a record is the 11th one?

Comment: Yep.  How else would you rank the 11th and 20th?  Without an ORDER BY, SQL Server can return to you any results it wants - order is not guaranteed.  Not sure how you're defining your ranking, but whatever field combo that is must go in the `order by`.

Answer (score 5):

**See following solution is applicable only for SQL Server 2012 onwards.**

Limit with offset in sql server:

```
SELECT email FROM myTable
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

//offset - no. of skipped rows

//next - required no. of next rows

Comment: The question is 2008 and that is a 2012 feature

Comment: @Blam: I have given answer because it can be helpful to people who are now using upgraded version of sql server. Do you want me to delete the answer if you feel it is misguiding to people. I have updated answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a sort field PK,

```
select top 10 * from MyTable
where PK not in (select top 10 PK from Mytable order by PK)
order by PK
```

Edit: here's a variant

```
select top 10 * from 
(select top 20 * from MyTable order by PK) as MySelection
order by PK desc
```

Comment: I think it is very tricky since when I need to select 21th to 30th, I need to write another tsql statement.

Comment: It's pretty easy to parametrize the query.

Comment: This looks like a nice solution. is it scalable? I.e. will there be any performance issues if the `MyTable` has 500,000 rows in it and you sometimes want rows 400,000 to 400,010?